# validate a Java POJO using JSON schema or equivalent?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

It's there a way or technology like JSON schema in which I get a JSON description of the data structure and I can validate in JAVA if fits the description.
I want something like JSON schema to validate incoming data, but I want to validate that the POJOs or Maps as Java objects, not the JSON document themselves.

Make the POJO a JSON just to validate it isn't a practical option, thanks!

is a way to do this with JSON schema or any other technologies?

UPDATE: SUMMARY 
AS far as I know: JSON Schema is a JSON document used to validate JSON documents. I want a schema written in JSON to validate Java POJOs.

the example below (I use the validate as a static function of class Validator ):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String schema = "{\n" +
                "  \"type\": \"object\",\n" +
                "  \"properties\": {\n" +
                "    \"street_address\": { \"type\": \"string\" },\n" +
                "    \"city\":           { \"type\": \"string\" },\n" +
                "    \"state\":          { \"type\": \"string\" }\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"required\": [\"street_address\", \"city\", \"state\"]\n" +
                "}";
        Object foo = new Hashtable();

        ((Map)foo).put("street_address","first street");
        ((Map)foo).put("street_address","The city");
        ((Map)foo).put("street_address","Not the USA");

        Validator validator = new Validator(schema);

        if (Validator.validate(foo, schema)) {
            System.out.println("It's validated");
        } else
            System.err.println("It isn't validated");
    }
```

Comment: what about http://hibernate.org/validator/ ?

Comment: I'm checking but till now it seems that works with annotations. I need to load the schema and validate it dynamically to objects that might or not be maps, in other words, any POJO object. can hibernate validator do this? can you elaborate on this?

Comment: You want something like an XSD for an XML to validate the JSON element, not the syntax. Correct ?

Comment: I was more or less aiming on the "equivalent", hibernate validation works only with annotations on the java class. But with a bit googling you could find this https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator (but I have no experience with this library)

Comment: I not sure if I understood your question. I need a validation mechanism for POJOs which is JSON based. In other words, using a JSON schema to validate if the POJO has all elements in it.

Comment: @Michal I think this is to validate a JSON using a JSON Schema. I want to use a schema written in JSON to validate a POJO

Comment: Ok my bad, you want the other way around. This will required reflection if you want a generic solution. If you let me some time. I would try this tonight.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I am looking for:   Using a json-schema spec to validate a Map.   I don't need bespoke POJO customizations.   Just need to walk the Map and validate.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the OPEN API: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification

This is the former SWAGGER TOOL ( https://swagger.io ) which allows to define objects in JSON / YAML / XML.
This is used a lot to:

1. Document your APIs and the objects you can receive
2. Generate client stubs based on the structure defined in the JSON
3. Help create test suites by integrating the JSONs in other tools (ex: postman)
4. etc

This allow you not only to document your POJOs but many other things in additional. It is quite powerful.

Comment: I know swagger (Open API) but this is for document/develop APIs and create its clients for RESTful API. I'm not even using REST in this case, so I do not see the usefulness swagger here. Thanks.

Comment: You are right. I added another answer. Check that one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just came accross this project which does exactly what you are asking for:
https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema

This is an example of a schema:

```
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "rectangle" : {"$ref" : "#/definitions/Rectangle" }
    },
    "definitions" : {
        "size" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "minimum" : 0
        },
        "Rectangle" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties" : {
                "a" : {"$ref" : "#/definitions/size"},
                "b" : {"$ref" : "#/definitions/size"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example JSON:

```
{
    "rectangle" : {
        "a" : -5,
        "b" : 5
    }
}
```

In this case the thrown `ValidationException` will point to `#/rectangle/a`.

```
try {
  schema.validate(rectangleSingleFailure);
} catch (ValidationException e) {
  // prints #/rectangle/a: -5.0 is not higher or equal to 0
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. But this validates a JSON document against a JSON Schema, not validate a Java POJO against a JSON schema. You can transform the POJO in a JSON but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [library](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator). You can validate Java POJO against JSON Schemas. It supports JSON schema v3 and v4.